# iOS: Should I release object in dealloc function?

Tags: ios, release

Im  very confused with the memory management.

Declared variable allNoticeArray in .h file:

```
@interface NoticeViewController : UITableViewController
{   
    NSMutableArray *allNoticeArray;    
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *allNoticeArray;
@end
```

Alloc and init the variable in .m file:

```
@implementation NoticeViewController
@synthesize allNoticeArray;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.allNoticeArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    /*
        ***should I release allNoticeArray here or not?***
    */
    //[allNoticeArray release];
}
```

Should I release the allNoticeArray in dealloc function or not?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When not using ARC you should use the release in the dealloc. You are right in saying that your retain in the .h file increases the retain count by one. The Alloc/Init creates an object with a retain count of one. The auto release would counter that retain, however your dealloc release would count the retain in the .h.

Setting self.allNoticeArray=nil; is not the same as a release, but the link from sElan is a great link.

Comment: @SuperGuyAbe Can u tell me why setting the property to nil wont work here? The setter will release the object behind the scene if you assign nil to it. Its safe to do releases in this way, and after all here a property has been used already.

Comment: @sElanthiraiyan thanks for calling me on this I have found a post that is very clear and it covers my reasoning, but also clarifies that your particular suggestion of self.allNoticeArray=nil would in fact work.  In general object=nil wouldn't release but on a property it would.  The link is [here](http://tinyurl.com/7zzl8pl)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're manually managing your memory rather than using ARC.

If you're using IOS5 it might be easier for you to [convert your project to ARC](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1), then you won't have to worry about dealloc in this context.

If you don't want to use ARC you do need to release it in this context because you alloc'd it in viewDidLoad. You might also be interested in [this article](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.co.nz/2010/09/dealloc.html) about dealloc.

Comment: This app, Im not using ARC and if do not release allNoticeArray in dealloc function, is there a leak?

Comment: If you don't release allNoticeArray in dealloc then yes, there will be a leak. The autorelease balances the allocation, but you still need to release in dealloc because you increase the retain count by one with the setter.

Comment: Thank you , and I will release the NSMutableArray in dealloc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to release the object. You could do the below in your dealloc method which will release your object.

```
self.allNoticeArray = nil;
```

**REASON:**
Although you have autoreleased the array you have declared your property as retain. So the object will be retained and used. So to totally remove the object from memory you should again call release over it. 
You can learn everything about memory management here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

Answer (score 2):

The rule of pre-ARC memory management is this:  if you alloc, retain, or copy an object you must release it later or it will leak.  Your property is set to retain, so whatever value it holds will be retained.  You must balance it with a release in dealloc.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is NO, but you are doing a few things that are not recommended.  In your code you are retaining your array twice in the single line.  In the code below it is only retain once.

You should initialize the array like so -

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
self.allNoticeArray = array;
```

I would recommend you look into using ARC, it makes memory management a non issue in IOS 5.

Comment: I retained allNoticeArray in .h file and alloc it in .m, so if do not release it in dealloc, is these a leak ?

Comment: I don't see how this makes a difference.  What OP has is perfectly acceptable.  It would be retained twice if it didn't have an autorelease on the end, but it does.  In fact it is identical to yours minus an extra variable.

Comment: It is not the same.  When you alloc init a property retain is called twice once for when you initialize it and once when you set it.  In my code retain is only called once.